# PHP session seemingly not working

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables

Session variables are apparently not working for me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is the code that I'm using to check for a valid password:

```
if ($input_password_hash == $password_hash)
 {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['is_user'] = 1;
  header("Location: ../new_look"); //or Location: index.php
 }
else echo "Wrong password.";
```

in the index.php file (where it redirects to), I have this code:

```
if ($_SESSION['is_user'] == 1)
{
  //show index page with navigation bar for registered user
}

else
{
 //do something else
}
```

but it's not working at all.

The session does apparently start and that can be verified by checking the cookie.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might be silly, but you do have "session_start();" on index.php, right? Your code looks like it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that you've got to write `session_start()` before you use the `$_SESSION` variable in any request, right? It looks like you haven't put it in index.php anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Session_start(); has to be placed before any header that will be sent out e.g. before any HTML tag on the php file.

Answer (score 1):

I just got back from fixing that...added `session_start()` right at the top of the file - even before the `<html>` tag. Doing `session_start()` in the middle gives errors...don't know why. I'm new to this. Thanks for your prompt response though.

Comment: session_start has to be called before any headers are sent, thats probably why it raised errors when you put in the middle.

Comment: Just a minor correction to Juan's comment.  session_start must be called before the body of the response is sent (other headers are fine).

Comment: Actually no, Juan is right. You can't even put the dtd before session_start(). I tried that. Put just the dtd, then session_start(), and it still threw the error.

Comment: Jim is referring to the HTTP headers, not the HTML head tag.