# PHP $_SESSION not working

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP session seemingly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490440/php-session-seemingly-not-working)

I'm currently coding my own CMS for fun but when I use $_SESSION, it doesn't work. The session isn't saved...

There's my code:

```
<?php
include('header.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
    $link = 'profile.php';
    $link_name = 'Profile';
}
else
{
    $link = 'login.php';
    $link_name = 'Login';
}

if (isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password = md5($password);
    $user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username`='".$username."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($user) == 1)
    {
            while ($userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($user))
            {
                    if ($userinfo['banned'] != true)
                    {
                            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userinfo['id'];
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $userinfo['username'];
                            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = "true";
                            header('Location: index.php');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            header('Location: login.php?error=banned');
                    }
            }
    }
    else if (mysql_num_rows($user) == 0)
    {
            header('Location: login.php?error=not-found');
    }
}
?>
```

In the code, I get the user information in my database then I check if the user isn't banned. If not, I set my $_SESSION[] and I redirect to the home...

Comment: Unless it's in `header.php`, you omitted `session_start()`.  You MUST call it before accessing or setting anything in `$_SESSION`, on each script where you access `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Do you have a session_start(); at the top of each page?

Comment: @Michael It is in `header.php`...

Comment: @dSquared Yeah, in `header.php`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need `session_start()` at first.

Comment: There is no such function in PHP.

Comment: @Frederick: the session, if _start()'d, will be automatically saved when the script exits. You can force a save with `session_write_close()`, but that prevents automatic saves later on if you do make any changes - you'd have to session_start() again to re-open it.

Comment: You always need to make sure there is no aberrant whitespace before your session_start(), as well. The best way to guard against this is to **never** put `?>` at the end of source code files.

Answer (score 4):

you should call `session_start()` in the beginning of the script. make sure you call it on every page you need the access to session variables as well

Answer (score 1):

Make sure session_start() is being called. Use Tamper Data to check the Headers for Sent and Received requests. Your looking for the Set-Cookie Header from the server and the Cookies Header from the client. This should contain your PHPSESSID. If you don't see this then your session is not started. Good Luck!