# I could not set the session variable in php

Tags: php, session-variables

Can any one please let me know, i have a issue on setting up session variables on my php site.
I have also checked with my `php_info()` where it is not enabled. But, the other sites in the same server are works fine. Please can any one advice on this to close?

Comment: You're gonna have to show some code

Comment: Sorry, it is restricted to company rules.

Comment: looks like were restricted in helping you

Comment: Sorry my magic ball got expired.... Now i have no idea about your code. Otherwise I would have given 100% working answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP session seemingly not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490440/php-session-seemingly-not-working) or one of [the other duplicates](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20sesson%20not%20working)

Answer (score 4):

```
session_start();
```

Make sure you have this at the top of your script. Its very common to forget that which can lead to frustrations of code not working. Like Marcus Adams said, you need that at the top of every script that will be accessing session variables.

Comment: Its all there, even it is not working...i have used it in my config file as included in all the pages in the site.

Comment: You should post your code so we can see what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: i have test  the session using two files.                                                              page 1
-------
session_start();

$_SESSION['mess']= "session value";


page 2
---------
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['mess'];

Comment: edit your original question and post your FULL code there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`session_start()`](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in every script where you intend to access session variables and call it before ANY output.

Also, ensure your browser has cookies enabled (most likely won't work if you're running PHP via the command line).

Use [`session_save_path()`](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) to get the location of the session save folder, and ensure your script has access.

If you need further help, please show us some codez and some error messages.