# Php echoing html div not working

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo a welcoming message of Welcome (the user's name)! and I have done this fine on a php file just plain flat out echoing it. On my index.html file however when I use the same code trying to surround it with a div it does not work... Is it my concatenation?
Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
<!---Sale Box--->
<center>
<div id="box">

<?php

session_start();
echo '<div id="text"> Welcome' . $_SESSION['username']. "</div>"

?>

</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Is the web server processing PHP code in a `.html` file?  It generally doesn't by default.  If you're seeing the actual PHP code client-side then that means it's not being treated as code server-side.  Renaming the file to `.php` would likely fix that.

Comment: `index.htm` The files says it already: `*.html` -> `*.php` <- your are using php so make a php file

Comment: Php code will not render in html page(index.html).Add the code in PHP Page(index.php)

Comment: Are you said you echoing it on .html file ?

Comment: Your `echo` needs a `;` at the end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP session seemingly not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490440/php-session-seemingly-not-working)

Comment: Yes I am echoing it on an html file.

Comment: @fedorqui i think its not a problem, as the echo is the last line from php code IMO

Comment: @Xela so change .html to .php then its solved.

Comment: @Xela if it was resolved, then accept answer by mohsenkw below. I dont mind with rep :D

Answer (score 2):

PHP cant be parsed in `.html`-files. Only if you reconfigure your Apache-Server to handle `.html` as same as he does with `.php`.

So your page must be `index.php` instead of `index.html`

Also you should take care to run this on a server where a apache is running or may install a local apache server to parse php. See [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html)

After this you have to echo like this (one possibility)

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!---Sale Box--->
<center>
<div id="box">

<?php echo "<div id='text'>Welcome {$_SESSION['username']}</div>"; ?>
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: "php cant be parsed by html": @Dwza: this is not true, it depends on your webserver settings.

Comment: @fpierrat actually you can do everything, even fly a airplane whitout any knowhow. So this comment is kind of useless! Even the devote. If you want to give him a lessen about "How to configure a apache server" go ahead. But this isnt the ops problem. By the way my answere is right and there is no need to devote!

Comment: @Dwza I did not downvote but the reason may have been because of what you *originally* said about *"php cant be parsed by html"* - That's not entirely true. `.html` files can run as PHP if Apache is instructed to treat `.html` files as PHP through an `.htaccess` directive. Yet, now I see you've made an edit about it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i know. But for his post this wasnt nessesary. But to have the answere correct I allready updated my post so this wont lead to wrong informations :)

Comment: @Dwza True. Questions like the OP's have been asked so many times already. But, your answer is indeed correct.

Comment: @Fred-ii- :) I guess that was your upvote. Thanks.

Comment: @Dwza My comment wasn't meant as an agression in any way, but as you seem to have taken it that way, then I do apologize. Still I believe one shouldn't give such peremptory answers as an absolute truth where it's just *most often* correct. There's no desire on my side to give any lesson on apache configuration, BUT I think that such an answer gives erroneous information, as well to OP as to future readers whose server might be configured differently. I see you've edited in the while so I upvoted, I suppose it should compensate previous downvote :-)

Comment: @fpierrat ok, may we just was talking on the same line... everything is fine and thx for the upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

you must use `session_start` ***before*** any output.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php : " ***Note:*** To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser."
    .

Comment: Actually yes you are right, but the wording isnt good. Let me edit :) Don't delete the answer in fear of down-votes. Your answer is correct. You might want to go ahead and undelete it.

Comment: Actually i just wanted to rewrite it after having the right source to quote... I got a doubt if this "before any output" stuff was for `session-start()` too, or just for `header()` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

change index.html to index.php

Comment: Then accept his answer madam/signore